# Problems with Linux scripting

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm relativity new to scripting and such but I'm trying to make a script that will run at a particular time which will backup a network drive to a off site destination.

I have the commands working manually and have figured out the timing but I am getting the following error when trying to run the script:

```
    cd /volume1/Data
    lftp -u [username],[password] [Destination]
    Mirror [directoryname] -R -n
```

Can't cd to volume1/Data, line 3 mirror not found.

I've to checked the capitalization and spelling.

hmmm

Answer (score 2):

`Mirror` is a lftp command, and the script executes it as if it were a shell command after the lftp process ends, which never happens, because the program is interactive, and waits for input. What you need to do is pass the lftp command to the standard input of lftp:

```
cd /volume1/Data 
echo "Mirror [directoryname] -R -n" | lftp -u [username],[password] [Destination]
```

Alternatively, you can use lftp's ability to execute scripts (check manual for `-f` option) and separate lftp commands into a separate file, then pass this file to lftp, or check out the `-e` option. It allows you to inline the lftp command into the parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `mirror` command to `lftp`:

```
cd /volume1/Data
user=joe
passwd=foo
host=myhost
dir=somedir

lftp -e "mirror $dir -R -n" -u $user,$passwd $host
```

Comment: -ash :cd : line 1 : cant cd to directory

Comment: are you sure the directory exists and you have permission to access it?

Comment: it does have a login for it should it be included in the script?

Comment: the full error was:
-ash :cd : line 1 : cant cd to directory
lftp: lftp:  name or service not known
mirror: not connected
1 error detected

sorry our internet went down

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a "here document" like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
host=Destination
user=username
pass=password
folder=directoryname
cd /volume1/Data
lftp -u $user,$pass $host  << EOF
mirror $folder -R -n
EOF
```

Comment: it meant what it said, just change it to a different directory you can write to (e.g. cd /home/myhome or cd /tmp on line 6)